# when apply class binding to mat-card, mat-card class is not binding

Tags: angular, angular-material, mat-card

when apply single class binding to mat-card, mat-card class is not binding.

```
<mat-card cdkDropList [className]="getClassName(item)"><!-- some content--></mat-card>
```

In this case we wont be able to see class name as mat-card and no style been applied from material.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the standard `[class]` binding, e.g.

```
<mat-card cdkDropList [class]="getClassName(item)">
  <!-- some content-->
</mat-card>
```

Example based on forked example from docs [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xmktec).

Comment: This worked. if class attribute is already existing too, it will append class from function.